# Does CGI code execute primarly on webserver?

Tags: html, bash, cgi

I have a CGI webpage with .cgi extension which should restore backups with user entered variables
Here it is:

```
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'
echo '<title>Form Example</title>'
echo '</head>'
echo '<body>'

  echo "<form method=GET action=\"${SCRIPT}\">"\
       '<table nowrap>'\
          '<tr><td>Restore bd</TD><TD><input type="text" name="val1" size=12 value=""></td></tr>'\
          '</tr></table>'

  echo '<input type="radio" name="val2" value="1" checked> test server№1<br>'\
       '<input type="radio" name="val2" value="2"> test server№2<br>'\

  echo '<br><input type="submit" value="run">'\
       '<input type="reset" value="cancel"></form>'


  if [ "$REQUEST_METHOD" != "GET" ]; then
        echo "<hr>Script Error:"\
             "<br>Usage error, cannot complete request, REQUEST_METHOD!=GET."\
             "<br>Check your FORM declaration and be sure to use METHOD=\"GET\".<hr>"
        exit 1
  fi
 
  if [ -z "$QUERY_STRING" ]; then
        exit 0
  else

     srv1=echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val1=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"
     srv2=echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val2=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"
     echo "DB: " $srv1
     echo '<br>'
     echo "SERVER: " $srv2

  fi
file=$(ssh -p 48563 root@$srv1 'ls -1t /app/docker/pg/backup/daily | head -n 1')
restore=$(echo $srv2)
if [ $restore -eq 1 ]
then
        scp -3 -P 48563 root@$srv1:/app/docker/pg/backup/daily/$file root@sv00dbtest01:/app/docker/pg/backup/$file
        ssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest01 "systemctl stop docker-compose"
        ssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest01 "rm -Rfv /app/docker/pg/data"
        ssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest01 "tar -zsxvf /app/docker/pg/backup/$file --strip=3 -C /app/docker/pg/"
        ssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest01 "systemctl start docker-compose"
        ssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest01 "rm -Rfv /app/docker/pg/backup/$file"
elif [ $restore -eq 2 ]
then
        scp -3 -P 48563 root@$srv1:/app/docker/pg/backup/daily/$file root@sv00dbtest02:/app/docker/pg/backup/$file
        ssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest02 "systemctl stop docker-compose"
        ssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest02 "rm -Rfv /app/docker/pg/data"
        ssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest02 "tar -zsxvf /app/docker/pg/backup/$file --strip=3 -C /app/docker/pg/"
        ssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest02 "systemctl start docker-compose"
        ssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest02 "rm -Rfv /app/docker/pg/backup/$file"
else
    echo "<br>"
    echo "<b>FAIL</b>"
    exit 0
fi
echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'

exit 0
```

When i run script it passes if-elif-else test and returns no FAIL message but it does not run targeted code aswell. I cant figure out whats wrong with it.
In which direction should i head?

Update:
I have apache running inside docker container
And command "docker logs apache" returned me huge error log:

```
[Thu Sep 24 18:03:13.797059 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 11] [client 10.24.136.2:63926] AH01215: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/php/restore5.cgi: line 142: ssh: command not found: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/php/restore5.cgi, referer: http://sv00gitlab01:8080/php/restore5.cgi?val1=sv00db03&val2=9
[Thu Sep 24 18:03:13.798201 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 11] [client 10.24.136.2:63926] AH01215: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/php/restore5.cgi: line 143: ssh: command not found: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/php/restore5.cgi, referer: http://sv00gitlab01:8080/php/restore5.cgi?val1=sv00db03&val2=9
[Thu Sep 24 18:03:13.798489 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 11] [client 10.24.136.2:63926] AH01215: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/php/restore5.cgi: line 144: ssh: command not found: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/php/restore5.cgi, referer: http://sv00gitlab01:8080/php/restore5.cgi?val1=sv00db03&val2=9
```

So i think there is not solution from this situation and i have to run apache outside container...

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors first (for instance the missing closing quote). BTW, what do you mean by _as you can see script passes if-elif-else test_, and how can I see this?

Comment: Done, edited the main text

Comment: If the command does not output FAIL, he must try to run some ssh commands. What does the stderr say?

Comment: Well ive never done it before.
Google says i can run stderr by typing: "find / -name filename >& /tmp/testfile"
And it returns no errors in terminal and also the file is empty

Comment: I don't understand what your `find` command has to do with your problem. In any case, if you want to know what is going on, you need to collect your stderr. Once you do this, you can run your script with `set -x` and then see each command which gets executed. Much easier than putting `echo` statements in every branch of your program, just for debugging.

Comment: The `srv1=echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed...` lines are wrong: you need [command substitution syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) there. Also, instead of using 5 separate ssh connections to each run one command, connect once and send 5 commands.

Comment: Guys i think i figured it out.
I have apache running inside docker container.
So when i perform ssh command there is not ssh inside container.
I found it our cchecking docker container logs.
[Thu Sep 24 18:03:13.798201 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 11] [client 10.24.136.2:63926] AH01215: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/php/restore5.cgi: line 143: ssh: command not found: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/php/restore5.cgi, referer: http://sv00gitlab01:8080/php/restore5.cgi?val1=sv00db03&val2=9

Comment: Thank you Glenn Jackmann and user1934428 for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found the solution so i guess ill post it here in case anyone will need it later on.
So i figured that you need to create another file with this code and run it:
if [ $restore -eq 1 ]
then

```
touch restore_script_db1.sh
chmod +x restore_script_db1.sh
echo -e "#!/usr/bin/env bash\n\nfile=\$(ssh -p 48563 root@$srv1 'ls -1t /app/docker/pg/backup/daily | head -n 1')\nscp -3 -P 48563 root@$srv1:/app/docker/pg/backup/daily/\$file root@sv00dbtest01:/app/docker/pg/backup/\$file\nssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest01 \"systemctl stop docker-compose\"\nssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest01 \"rm -Rfv /app/docker/pg/data\"\nssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest01 \"tar -zsxvf /app/docker/pg/backup/\$file --strip=3 -C /app/docker/pg/\"\nssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest01 \"chown -R 1000:1000 /app/docker/pg/data\"\nssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest01 \"systemctl start docker-compose\"\nssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest01 \"rm -Rfv /app/docker/pg/backup/$file\"\nssh -p 48563 root@sv00dbtest01 \"docker exec server1c /opt/1C/v8.3/x86_64/rac infobase update --cluster=7f122b3b-799c-4c98-a98f-4953a78eff48 --infobase=5d0b3f1b-16f4-4d6a-8fac-0e746887f71d --infobase-user=rac_adm --infobase-pwd=123 --db-server=$srv1\"" >> restore_script_db1.sh
sh restore_script_db1
```